# Dynamic Programming - Edges difference problem

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, dynamic-programming, directed-graph

I just started learning about Dynamic Programming, and in my assignment I was required to describe an algorithm that solves the following problem:

---

Let G be a directed graph, where every edge is colored either green or yellow, and a source vertex s. For every vertex in V, find a path that the difference between the number of green and yellow edges is minimal. That algorithm needs to be O(|V|+|E|) complexity for each vertex.

- **Input**: Given a directed graph G=(V, E), a source vertex s in V and edges colored with this coloring function: For every edge e in the graph, c(e)->{yellow, green}. There is a path to every vertex v in V from the source vertex s.
- **The weight of a path 'P' in the graph**, is the difference between the number of green edges and the number of yellow edges in the graph
- **Output**: For every vertex v in V, return the minimal weight of a path P from s to v.

---

So I started thinking about a solution to this problem. I realized that I can exchange the colors with numbers, -1 and 1 and work from there, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution.

My most fleshed out solution looks at the group of neighbors of target a vertex and does the following:

- Find the minimum weight between:

  - The sum of the "weight" of the edge (-1, 1) leading to a vertex 'k' from the current vertex's neighbor group, and the optimum of 'k'.
  - The optimum of the other neighbors, excluding the vertex 'k'.
- terminate when reaching s or the neighbors group is empty.

However, this solution doesn't feel right, as it doesn't look at a vertex - but at a group of vertices, and I don't think it meets the complexity demands. I tried writing the formula: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdaOA.jpg)

I tried experimenting with solutions that start from the vertex s and end at a target vertex v, but I was unable to reach a solid termination condition. For example, it can't terminate when reaching v, since there might be cycles involving v that result in a minimum result.

I was hoping to get some guidance on this problem, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily strike me as a case for dynamic programming, so maybe I've missed something and there's a quicker dynamic solution, but you can achieve an O(VE) running time using a modified Bellman-Ford. This asymptotic time bound is not the same as O(V + E) per vertex! But for a connected graph (since the source can reach all the vertices) it is the same overall.

I'll leave you to look up the details of the Bellman Ford algorithm (for single source shortest paths), in the spirit of it being an assignment, but suffice it to say that your vertices could store a positive score for more yellow than green, a negative score for the opposite, and their weight in either case would be the absolute value of this attribute. Your 'relax' function would then operate as follows, assuming we use a score attribute on each vertex (this score is not the weight, it can be positive or negative):

```
        RELAX(u, v):
            new_score = u.score
            if the edge u -> v is green:
                new_score -= 1
            else:
                new_score += 1
            if abs(new_score) < v.score:
                v.score = new_score
```